# Recibir datos de Tabla con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo una tabla la cual tiene la informacion que mando a llamar de una base de datos. La idea que tengo es que al momento de darle click a un `<input type="submit">`, este reciba los datos de cada `<tr>` que pertenece al `<td>` para enviarlo a otra pagina en la cual ocupare estos datos.

Esta es la tabla de la cual quiero recibir los datos:

```html
<form action="Registro_Producto_Dañado.php" method="post">
  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Producto</th>
      <th class="text-center">Fecha Elaboracion</th>
      <th class="text-center">Fecha Vencimiento</th>
      <th class="text-center">Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-inventario-producto">
    
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </form>
```

Esta es la funcion controlador en el cual imprimo la informacion de cada `<tr>`:

```js
$.ajax({
        url:"ajax/api.php?accion=obtener-lista-inventario-productos",
        method:"GET",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(respuesta){
            for(var i=0;i<respuesta.length;i++){
                $('#table-inventario-producto').append(
                    '<tr>'+
                    '<td class="text-center" name="nombreProducto">'+respuesta[i].nombre+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center" name="fechaElaboracion">'+respuesta[i].fechaElaboracion+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center" name="fechaVencimiento">'+respuesta[i].fechaVencimiento+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center" name="cantidadBandejas">'+respuesta[i].cantidadBandejas+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" value="Eliminar Producto"></td>'+
                    '</tr>'
                );
            }
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

Y esta es la pagina a la cual quiero enviar la informacion, la cual se debera de llenar en el formulario

```html
<?php

  $nombreProducto = $_POST['nombreProducto'];
  $fechaElaboracion = $_POST['fechaElaboracion'];
  $fechaVencimiento = $_POST['fechaVencimiento'];
  $cantidadBandejas =$_POST['cantidadBandejas'];

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Registrar_Producto_Dañado</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
    <link href="css/menu-empleado.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!--- aqui incluyo el menu-->

<?php
include ("menu.html") ;
?> 
    
  <section class="form-register">
      <h5>Registrar el Producto Dañado</h5>
      <tr>
        <h4>Producto</h4>
        <input class="controls" type="text" name="Nombres" id="" placeholder="nombreProducto">
        <tr>
      <tr>
        <h4>Fecha de Elaboraciòn </h4>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txt-fecha" placeholder="Fecha de registro">
     
      <tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <h4>Fecha de Vencimiento</h4>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txt-fecha" placeholder="Fecha de registro">
     <tr>
       
        
      </tr>
      
          <h4>Cantidad</h4>
        </tr>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txt-cantidad-eliminar" placeholder="Cantidad">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Eliminar Producto">
  </section>


  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
  <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controlador.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: El atributo `name` está reservado para elementos de formulario y tú lo estás usando para elementos de tabla. Aparte, lo normal es que envíes solo ID del producto y en la siguiente página, primero valides, luego obtengas el resto de información desde la base de datos, armando el formulario.

Comment: @Triby , entonces lo que podria hacer es que en vez de enviarle el name, le envie el id? Y que la informacion que se agarre en el php sea del id?